# Execute vim in a loop

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am writing a script which will let the user edit more than 1 files. I'm trying to launch `vim` for every file.

I've tried putting the filenames in an array and iterate over every element of array and launch vim in every iteration. but this only launches `vim` for the first element and the script stops. How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Please put the code of your script in the question!

Comment: why not just use `vim "${arrayname[@]}"`? It has the same effect as running vim in a loop (user edits each file sequentially, one after another) but also allows movement back and forth between those files, as well as Yank + Paste between them.  With `gvim` you can even select the file from the Buffers menu.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a file description different from stdin if you want to run something interactive inside the loop.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while read -r file <&3; do

  vim "$file" || break

done 3< <(find . -type f)
```

Alternatively, with null-byte separators to support unusual file names:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r -d '' file <&3; do

  vim -- "$file" || break

done 3< <(find . -type f -print0)
```

The output of `find` is fed with the help of process substitution to the file descriptor 3 which is then fed to `read` through `<&3`.

/edit: As per Wolf's suggestion from the comments.

Comment: This is great. I recommend using `vim "$file" || break` so that you terminate the loop if something fails, or you want to stop (by doing `:cq` in Vim).

Answer (score 2):

For me this works:

```
#!/bin/sh

for f in *.txt
do
    vim "$f"
done
```

It opens a vim for each file, and opens the next after having closed the previous.